# Mocha: How to add expectation of a method when there are multiple invocations with different parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-mocha

I have a Rails controller action to test. In that action, a method User.can? is invoked several times with different parameters. In one of the test case for it, I want to make sure that User.can?('withdraw') is invoked. But I don't care about invocations of User.can? with other parameters.

```
def action_to_be_tested
  ...
  @user.can?('withdraw')
  ...
  @user.can?('deposit')
  ...
end
```

I tried below in the test:

```
User.any_instance.expects(:can?).with('withdraw').at_least_once.returns(true)
```

But the test failed with message indicating unexpected invocation of User.can?('deposit').
If I add another expectation with parameter 'deposit', the test passed. But I am wondering if there are any ways such that I could just focus on the invocation with 'withdraw' parameter (because other invocations are irrelevant to this test case).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just found a workaround, by stubbing out invocations with irrelevant parameters:

```
User.any_instance.expects(:can?).with('withdraw').at_least_once.returns(true)
User.any_instance.stubs(:can?).with(Not(equals('withdraw')))
```

http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html#M000023

Comment: I was aware [the API](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#with-instance_method) supported literal values (direct comparisons to variables), or yielding to the block, but I'm not sure where the `Not(...)` construct comes from.  Could you speak to that in more detail?

Comment: @Pysis `Not()` comes from the [Mocha::ParameterMatchers](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html) that are used with `with()`. They can be camel case like `HasKey()` or snake case like `has_key()`. `Not` has to be camel case because it's a keyword, though.

Answer (score 24):

You can pass a block to `with` and have that block inspect the arguments. Using that, you can construct a list of expected invocations:

```
invocations = ['withdraw', 'deposit']
User.any_instance.expects(:can?).at_most(2).with do |permission|
  permission == invocations.shift
end
```

Each time `can?` is called, Mocha will yield to the block. The block will pull the next value off the list of expected invocations and check it against the actual invocation.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it does exactly what is wanted.

Comment: This hasn't work for me, no matter what. The marked answer below worked though.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler version from @Innerpeacer version would be:

```
User.any_instance.stubs(:can?).with(any_parameters)
User.any_instance.expects(:can?).with('withdraw')
```